# Rails 3 assertions failure message: "Expected block to return true value" not helpful; what gives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, tdd

This occurs frequently in my controller and route tests.  Example, given the route

```
match "/about", :to => "about#profile"
```

And the test

```
test "/about goes to about/profile" do
  assert_generates "/about/", { :controller => "about", :action => "profile" }
end
```

The only failure message is "Expected block to return true value".  This happens also with tests like:

```
test "bills should redirect to /bills" do
  get :bills
  assert_redirected_to user_bills_path(@user)
end
```

If my controller doesn't' redirect to `user_bills_path(@user)`, I get the same error: "Expected block to return true value"

This is very annoying for test-driving, as I cannot easily check that my assertion is failing before writing production code or failing because I've written the incorrect test.

It seems to be coming from Rails testing stuff.  Any way to avoid this or get better messages?